# trying to rotate an image in pygame for movement

Tags: python, pygame, rotation

im new to programming so im following some tutorials online to make a basic game. in order to create the movement for my character, i followed this tutorial
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4aZe84vvE20&t=692s&ab_channel=ClearCode
after following the rotation part of the video, i tried testing it out. however, it does not work for some reason. im not sure why this is. i do not get an error, but the character stays in one place and does not rotate once i press the left and right arrow keys. could somebody have a look at my code and let me know what i have done wrong? thanks a lot

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((650, 650))
pygame.display.set_caption  ("Game")
green = (0,255,0)
window.fill(green)

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
   def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()
      self.og_image = pygame.image.load("player1.png")
      self.image = self.og_image
      self.rect = self.image.get_rect (center = (345,345))
      self.angle = 0
      self.rotate_speed = 1        
      self.direction = 0     

   def rotate(self):
      if self.direction == 1:
         self.angle -= self.rotate_speed
         print(self.angle)
      elif self.direction == -1:
         self.angle += self.rotate_speed
         print(self.angle)
      self.image = pygame.transform.rotozoom(self.og_image, self.angle, 1)
      self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (self.rect.center))
   def update(self):     
      self.rotate()
      
player_1 = Player()
players = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()
players.add(player_1)
players.draw(window)

run = True

while run == True:
   
   for event in pygame.event.get():          
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:          
         run = False

      if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
         if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            players.sprite.direction += 1
         if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            players.sprite.direction -= 1
            
      if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
         if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            players.sprite.direction -= 1
         if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            players.sprite.direction += 1

      players.update()

      pygame.display.update()



pygame.quit()
```

Comment: I'm really sorry. I've been busy for the past few days. Will hopefully get back to it in the coming days. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to draw the *Sprites* in the *Group* (`players.draw(window)`) and you have to clear the display (`window.fill(green)`) before drawing the objects. Note, you have to do this in the application loop rather than the event loop (It's a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html)):

[image]

```py
run = True

while run == True:
   
    for event in pygame.event.get():          
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:          
            run = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                players.sprite.direction += 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                players.sprite.direction -= 1
                
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                players.sprite.direction -= 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                players.sprite.direction += 1

    # INDENTATION

    #<--|

    players.update()

    window.fill(green)
    players.draw(window)
    pygame.display.update()
```